# Decrypting OpenAuth password with password and salt

Tags: c#, .net, encryption, passwords

I have inherited a project (written in ASP.NET C#) which uses OpenAuth for the validation of users when logging in to the website.  I have never used OpenAuth before.  In the SQL Server database, there is one username in the 'Memberships' table and I need to be able to log in as this user.  I have the password and salt.  Does anyone know how to decrypt the password?

Thanks

Comment: The whole point of hashing is that to make that completely impossible.  Also, OAuth doesn't use passwords at all.

Comment: Why don't you just create a new user with a password you know or replace that user's passsword hash & salt with one you know?

Answer (score 1):

Hashed passwords cannot be decrypted.
You can find more info about OAuth Security [here](http://hueniverse.com/oauth/guide/security/).